# How to speed up MySQL query? Loading data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have 3 tables. 
First: "atributy"
Second: "atributy_value"
Third: "produkty"

I have this query first:

```
SELECT a.*, p.ATTRIBUTE_CODE, p.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, p.KATEGORIA  
FROM atributy a JOIN produkty p ON p.ATTRIBUTE_CODE
LIKE CONCAT('%', a.code, '%')
AND
KATEGORIA IN ('$kategoria_sql') 
GROUP BY a.value
```

And my second query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM atributy_value
INNER JOIN produkty 
ON produkty.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE LIKE CONCAT('%', atributy_value.ValueCode, '%')
AND AttributeCode = '$atribut_kod' 
AND KATEGORIA IN ('$kategoria_sql')
GROUP BY atributy_value.Value
```

Help me please make from this 2 query's 1 one better.
Reason: too long loading my web e-shop.

EDIT:

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT a.*, p.ATTRIBUTE_CODE, p.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, p.KATEGORIA  
FROM atributy a JOIN produkty p ON p.ATTRIBUTE_CODE LIKE CONCAT('%', a.code, '%') 
AND KATEGORIA IN ('$kategoria_sql') 
GROUP BY a.value ");

while($result = mysql_fetch_object($query)){

$atribut_kod = $result->code;
$atribut_value = $result->value;
$nazov_produktu = $result->NAZOV;
$value1 = $result->ATTRIBUTE_VALUE;
$value1 = explode(" ", $value1);

$value1_count = count($value1);

echo "<div class=\"parametre_panel\">
<h3>".$atribut_value."</h3>
";

$url_kody .= "$atribut_kod,";

$hodnoty_qry = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM atributy_value
INNER JOIN produkty ON produkty.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE LIKE CONCAT('%', atributy_value.ValueCode, '%')
AND AttributeCode = '$atribut_kod' 
AND KATEGORIA IN ('$kategoria_sql')  
GROUP BY atributy_value.Value ");

 while($hodnoty_res = mysql_fetch_object($hodnoty_qry)){
 $cislo_hodnoty = $hodnoty_res->ValueCode;
 echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"ZobrazParametrickeVyhladavanie\"   name=\"value[]\" id=\"$cislo_hodnoty\" value=\"".$atribut_kod."-".$cislo_hodnoty."\"><label for=\"$cislo_hodnoty\">".$hodnoty_res->Value."</label>
 ";

 $url_hodnoty .= "$cislo_hodnoty,";
} //second query while()
echo "</div>";
} //first query while()
```

EDIT 2:

My table structure

```
produkty:       http://i.imgur.com/J4Kz2CE.png 
atributy_value: http://i.imgur.com/nX1uRph.png 
atributy:       http://i.imgur.com/mlCa3It.png
```

Indexes:

```
atributy:         http://i.imgur.com/ppMEEOe.png
atributy_value:   http://i.imgur.com/RHAeSiu.png
produkty:         http://i.imgur.com/IUrgy9l.png
```

Comment: You havent provide much info. YOu can have wrong indexes, queries can be too complicated, when its not neccessary etc. Your answer can not be answered correctly, without knowing more info.

Comment: Does your while Loop runs perfectly? i mean Is there any error? Since I am seeing a variable name in Dynamic Query.

Comment: Yes this works but very long loading :(

Comment: could you list the columns and datatypes in the three tables? Especially the primary keys, and if there is any foreign key linking the two tables together.

Comment: Edited post. I add screenshots of my indexes and strucure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try Below Query:**

```
SELECT a.*, 
       p.ATTRIBUTE_CODE, 
       p.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, 
       p.KATEGORIA  
  FROM atributy a 
  JOIN (SELECT * 
          FROM atributy_value
         INNER JOIN produkty 
            ON produkty.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE LIKE CONCAT('%', atributy_value.ValueCode, '%')
           AND AttributeCode = '$atribut_kod' 
           AND KATEGORIA IN ('$kategoria_sql')
         GROUP BY atributy_value.Value) p 
    ON p.ATTRIBUTE_CODE LIKE CONCAT('%', a.code, '%')
   AND KATEGORIA IN ('$kategoria_sql') 
 GROUP BY a.value
```

*In Inner Query Select Only Required Columns*

Hope this works.

Comment: `$atribut_kod` is in while() first query.

Comment: Which `While()`? You have not mentioned Loop anywhere in your post. Please Provide details information so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are slow here.

First - unnecessary outer / inner loop.  It should be possible to do this in a single SQL query, which will be a huge time saving.
Without seeing the definitions of your tables, this is the best I can suggest :

```
 SELECT a.*, p.*, av.*
 FROM produkty p 
 JOIN atributy a ON p.ATTRIBUTE_CODE LIKE CONCAT('%', a.code, '%') 
 JOIN atributy_value av ON p.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE LIKE CONCAT('%', av.ValueCode, '%') 
 WHERE 
 KATEGORIA IN ('$kategoria_sql')
```

At least it's a starting point to test from.

Second - Joining between the two tables using LIKE '%value%'.  Is there not an integer ID that links these two tables together? Or at least, should the text be an exact match and you can remove the '%'s?

EDIT (after adding table structure) :

You have two joins, the first from a nice indexed integer atributy_value.ValueCode to a non-indexed text field produkty.ATTRIBUTE_CODE, the second from a non indexed text field atributy.code to another non-indexed text field produkty.ATTRIBUTE_CODE.

It's not a good table structure, it would be easier and faster if every table had a unique integer ID to join on.  But you might not have time to change this.

Can you just remove the %'s in your original queries and insist on an exact match between the columns?
To keep it simple, you could just replace :

```
LIKE CONCAT('%', a.code, '%')
```

replace with

```
= a.code
```

and

```
LIKE CONCAT('%', atributy_value.ValueCode, '%')
```

replace with

```
= CONVERT( varchar(500), atributy_value.ValueCode)
```

This will make it faster.  If it's still not enough you could add indexes on Produkty.ATTRIBUTE_CODE and Produkty.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE and atributy.code.

Comment: why searching for LIKE '%value%' is slow : http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/

Comment: Muste be LIKE because the values ​​greater than 1. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/p4EH1gt.png

Comment: storing multiple values in one column is bad practice in a database ... it causes problems exactly like this.  Even adding indexes to these text columns will not make it faster, because the index is only useful to look up strings where the first characters are known.
The only suggestion I have left is to replace the outer / inner query with a single query like my example SQL - have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. I have this now: http://i.imgur.com/WiULHYS.jpg and error: `Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /data/i/t/domain-name_1/domain name/web/index.php on line 488` and mysq_error() says: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(500), atributy_value.ValueCode) WHERE KATEGORIA IN ('Notebooky','')' at line 4`

Comment: try the original version in my answer, still using LIKE + CONCAT ?

Comment: Now: `Query execution was interrupted` Im using LIKE CONCAT.. I tried replace with `LIKE '%av.ValueCode'` and  `LIKE '%a.code%'` ..not working :(

Answer (score 0):

1) Run an EXPLAIN on your queries and add indexes where necessary. IMHO, these queries are not meant to run on production. However, I have made a suggestion below.

2) Let MySQL handle the query execution plan for you. Instead of mentioning a JOIN. Try this

```
$query = mysql_query("
                        SELECT a.*, p.ATTRIBUTE_CODE, p.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, p.KATEGORIA 
                        FROM atributy a,produkty p 
                        WHERE p.ATTRIBUTE_CODE LIKE CONCAT('%', a.code, '%') 
                        AND KATEGORIA IN ('$kategoria_sql') 
                        GROUP BY a.value ");
```

2) Also change the inner query to the following:

```
SELECT atributy_value.* FROM atributy_value AS atributy_value, produkty AS produkty  
WHERE 
produkty.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE LIKE CONCAT('%', atributy_value.ValueCode, '%')
AND atributy_value.AttributeCode = '$atribut_kod' 
AND produkty.KATEGORIA IN ('$kategoria_sql')  
GROUP BY atributy_value.Value ")
```

I need more details on the table structures though

3) Run an EXPLAIN on the above query. If you have any missing indexes, please add them

Comment: surely you need to specify the JOIN to tell mysql the relationship you want between the tables?  Otherwise you'll just get every combination from the tables.

Comment: Edited post. I add screenshots of my indexes and strucure

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths: No, you don't need to. MySQL actually does it by itself. In the above example SELECT atributy_value.* FROM atributy_value AS atributy_value, produkty AS produkty  
WHERE 
produkty.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE LIKE CONCAT('%', atributy_value.ValueCode, '%') is the same as doing an INNER JOIN. Of course, it doesn't help the fact that the join in the above example is done using LIKE (the worst kind). Hence, taking it out of the join allows MySQL to deal with it.

Comment: @DavidLences: Hi, did you do an EXPLAIN in front of your generated queries? Try it out, it will help

Comment: @HariRamamurthy Hi, this is screenshot of explain: http://i.imgur.com/4c8T0oh.jpg . The "EXPLAIN SELECT" is new for me.